# Set Variable If returns none robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am a newbie to Robot Framework and when running the below the varible ${month} reutns back 'none'.

What I am trying to do is convert the month as a number to its relevant month in text e.g. 1 to January, 4 to April etc.

I am sure this will be a simple fix but I have no idea what it is ... Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
${month int}  Get Current Date  result_format=%m
Log To Console  month int=${month int} 

${month} =  Set Variable If  '${month int}' >= 13  Fail
${month} =  Set Variable If  '${month int}' == '01'  January
${month} =  Set Variable If  '${month int}' == '02'  Febuary
${month} =  Set Variable If  '${month int}' == '03'  March
${month} =  Set Variable If  '${month int}' == '04'  April
${month} =  Set Variable If  '${month int}' == '05'  May
${month} =  Set Variable If  '${month int}' == '06'  June
${month} =  Set Variable If  '${month int}' == '07'  July
${month} =  Set Variable If  '${month int}' == '08'  August
${month} =  Set Variable If  '${month int}' == '09'  September
${month} =  Set Variable If  '${month int}' == '10'  October
${month} =  Set Variable If  '${month int}' == '11'  November
${month} =  Set Variable If  '${month int}' == '12'  December

Log To Console  month string=${month}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is doing exactly what you ask him to do. Look at it: in the last line you say

```
${month} =  Set Variable If  '${month int}' == '12'  December
```

And thus `${month}` is set to `None` because `${month int}` is not 12 and `None` is the default value for the case that the given condition is not true. You need to use `else if` logic and this is done this way in Robotframework:

```
${month} =  Set Variable If  '${month int}' >= 13  Fail
...  '${month int}' == '01'  January
...  '${month int}' == '02'  Febuary
...  '${month int}' == '03'  March
...  '${month int}' == '04'  April
...  '${month int}' == '05'  May
...  '${month int}' == '06'  June
...  '${month int}' == '07'  July
...  '${month int}' == '08'  August
...  '${month int}' == '09'  September
...  '${month int}' == '10'  October
...  '${month int}' == '11'  November
...  '${month int}' == '12'  December
```

See [Documentation to "Set Variable If"](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If).

Comment: I tried the above and the below now gives me 'fail' but the month is 11, as can be seen in   Log To Console  month int=${month int}.    ${month int}    Get Current Date  result_format=%m
Log To Console  month int=${month int}
  ${month} =  Set Variable If  '${month int}' >= 13  Fail
    ...  '${month int}' == '01'  January
    ...  '${month int}' == '02'  Febuary
    ...  '${month int}' == '03'  March
  etc

  Log To Console  month string=${month}
  Compare strings  css=div[class='a-month']  ${month}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the comparison fails (maybe you're comparing integer to a string?) but you can circumvent the problem by using the dateTime object:

```
${month int}  Get Current Date  result_format=datetime
Log To Console  month int=${datetime.month}
${month} =  Set Variable If  ${datetime.month} >= 13  Fail
${month} =  Set Variable If  ${datetime.month} == 1  January
${month} =  Set Variable If  ${datetime.month} == 2  Febuary
${month} =  Set Variable If  ${datetime.month} == 3  March
....
```

Comment: Thanks i tried this but unfortunately still got 'none'. I also tried Convert To String but this didnt resolve either.

Answer (score 0):

Below script might solve your issue.Please check once

[image]